# Can someone please create tags for 歳-counter, age-counter and 歳?

Tags: support, tags

I have a question about my Japanese Language Stack Exchange post: [Can the 歳 counter be used for architecture, furniture etc to tell it's age?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/67911/can-the-%e6%ad%b3-counter-be-used-for-architecture-furniture-etc-to-tell-its-age)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions about counters should be tagged [counters](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counters) (with [counter-words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-words) being a synonym).

I don't think it would be useful to create tags for all individual counters. (We do have individual tags for different particles, but the grammar of counters is usually the same, so it makes sense to just use one tag here.)

Comment: Oh okay. Hank you gor the clarification. I did not know what all tags could be used since this is the first time I am posting a query. I'll keep this in mind for future work.

Comment: @Shivangi: See here for more info on tags: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/tagging